# Android How to Deserialize the Json String Using Pojo Class

Tags: android, json, retrofit

**I Am getting this Json Response from server how to deseriallize the json string**

`{
        "results": {
            "status": "true",
            "message": "Successfully Get Data",
            "PdfData": {
                "Pdf_Result": [{
                    "Pdf_File_Name": "aft.pdf",
                    "Subject_Name": "Maths",
                    "Subject_Id": "1",
                    "Chapter_ID": "M1111",
                    "Chapter_Name": "Relations and Functions",
                    "Downloaded": "YES"
                }, {
                    "Pdf_File_Name": "date.pdf",
                    "Subject_Name": "Maths",
                    "Subject_Id": "1",
                    "Chapter_ID": "M1112",
                    "Chapter_Name": "Algebra",
                    "Downloaded": "YES"
                }]
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

see jsonschema2pojo.org site and Gson library tutorial

Answer (score 0):

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

This tutorials will teach you how to parse with Json using Gson

Comment: Yaa i know how to create pojo class but i want to know how to get Pdf_Result(Array data ) using custom deserializer class for this response

Comment: you mean how to parse data?

Comment: Yes @Mohit i want to parse data but using custom Deserializer class that give status , message and pdf_Result data

Comment: so in that case use Gson

Comment: Yes using Gson how to get desire data from json string ...can provide some example